# Resize constraints for UIView. swift

Tags: ios, animation, view, constraints

I have two custom UIViews on the screen. UIViewOne occupies 75% of the screen, and UIViewTwo 25%. I need to click on UIViewTwo, resize it to make the second bigger and smaller first.
I also know that this needs to be done using constraints, but I don't know how. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: hi, share some code and a bit more explanation is required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to add **two** Height constraints to `view1` and change their **Priority**,

- add a Height constraint at 75% (`multiplier = 0.75`)
- set its Priority to `999`
- add a Height constraint at 25% (`multiplier = 0.25`)
- set its Priority to `998`
- constraint the Top of `view2` to the bottom of `view1`.

At the start, the 75% Height constraint will have priority over the 25% constraint ... `999` *is greater than* `998`. When you tap `view2`, change the 75% constraint's Priority to `997`. Now `997` *is less than* `998`, so the 25% constraint gets the priority.

Since `view2`'s top is constrained to `view1`'s bottom, `view2` will automatically resize.

Here is an example you can run as-is (just assign it to a view controller... no `IBOutlet` or `IBAction` connections needed):

```
class PercentViewController: UIViewController {

    let view1: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    let view2: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()

    var topView75: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var topView25: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // we're using auto-layout
        view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // add views
        view.addSubview(view1)
        view.addSubview(view2)

        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // create "75% height constraint"
        topView75 = view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.75)
        // create "25% height constraint"
        topView25 = view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25)

        // give 75% constraint higher priority than 25% constraint
        topView75.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        topView25.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 998)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // view1 constrained Top, Leading, Trailing (to safe-area)
            view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            view1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // view2 constrained Bottom, Leading, Trailing (to safe-area)
            view2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            view2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // view2 Top constrained to view1 Bottom
            view2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.bottomAnchor),

            // activate both Height constraints
            topView75,
            topView25,

        ])

        // create tap gesture recognizers
        let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(view1Tapped(_:)))
        let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(view2Tapped(_:)))

        // add to the views
        view1.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
        view2.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)

    }

    @objc func view1Tapped(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        // view1 tapped, so give 75% constraint a higher priority than 25% constraint
        topView75.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        // 0.3-second animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @objc func view2Tapped(_ sender: Any) -> Void {
        // view2 tapped, so give 25% constraint a higher priority than 75% constraint
        topView75.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 997)
        // 0.3-second animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir, thank you more, your answer really helped me !!

Comment: @JiosDev - if the answer works for you, be sure to mark it Accepted (for the benefit of anyone else who comes across it).

Comment: Please tell me how to do this to superView?

Comment: @JiosDev - what do you mean by "to superView"?

Comment: I replace let layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide on  let layoutGuide = view.superView. Here is what I need to change, but I don’t know how to fix errors in the code

Comment: @JiosDev - In that case, `view` has no `superView`. Are you asking how to put the 75% / 25% views in another `UIView`, which is a subview of `view`?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I still have a question. I put on the background of each kind of image, and noticed that they overlap each other. How to make it so that they decrease and keep their contents with them, rather than being covered by another view.?

Comment: @JiosDev - hard to say, because that's really a new question. Do you have `.clipsToBounds = true` on your views? Are you using `scale to fill` or `aspect fit / fill` on the images?

Comment: `clipsToBounds = true` on view and `.aspectFill` on image

Comment: @JiosDev - ok... then what do you mean exactly by `put on the background of each kind of image`? Did you change the views to `UIImageView`s? Or did you add `UIImageView` as subview?

Comment: I took UIImage and laid it on the View. To make it like a background

Comment: @JiosDev - view code or storyboard? *"laid it on the view"* ... do you mean made it a **subview**? Or you put it **on top of** the view? If subview, make sure the view *also* has `clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Okay. I have a main storyboard and two views on it. View1 and View2. Each of these view is made using .xib. In addition, each view has a UIImage as its background. Your View resizing code helped me, but I don’t need them to overlap, but to decrease or increase them with their contents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206735/discussion-between-donmag-and-jiosdev).

Answer (score 3):

For both view1 and view2,

1. add constraint as **equal height to superview**
2. update the **height constraint multiplier** to 0.75 for view1 and  0.25 for view2.

When you click on view2, similarly update the height constraint multiplier to 0.25 for view1 and 0.75 for view2.

Comment: Could you show an example of the code that you wrote?