# Change Automatic layout restrictions by swipe

Tags: ios, swift, animation, resize, constraints

There are two pictures on the screen, they are programmatically set restrictions. On the swipe to the left, the pictures change size and become as they should. If after that, swipe to the right, then nothing happens and the pictures remain in their places.
Here is the implementation code.

```
func Swipe() {
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    }

    @objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        if gesture.direction == .right {


            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations:{

                self.setupLayoutImageOne()
            }, completion: nil)
             self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        } else if gesture.direction == .left {


            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations:{
                self.setupLayoutImageTwo()

            }, completion: nil)
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }


    func setupLayoutImageOne()
    {

       imageOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       imageTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let layoutGuide = view

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([


            imageOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.topAnchor),
            imageOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.leadingAnchor),
            imageOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.trailingAnchor,constant: 170) ,
            imageOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.bottomAnchor,constant: 290),


           imageTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.bottomAnchor,constant: 530),
           imageTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.leadingAnchor,constant: 200),
           imageTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.trailingAnchor,constant: 200),
           imageTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.topAnchor,constant: 800),

            ])

    }
    func setupLayoutImageTwo()
    {

       imageOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       imageTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let layoutGuide = view

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([


           imageOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.topAnchor),
           imageOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.leadingAnchor),
           imageOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.trailingAnchor,constant: 299) ,
           imageOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.bottomAnchor,constant: 570),


           imageTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.bottomAnchor),
           imageTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.leadingAnchor),
          imageTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.trailingAnchor),
           imageTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.topAnchor),
            ])

    }
```

When I make swipe to the right, it gives out such errors

> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   
>   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x10080e7a0 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. Fatal error: Unexpectedly
>   found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value 2020-01-28
>   15:09:59.920450+0200 ThemeGame[27748:2857822] Fatal error:
>   Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: You cannot keep adding different constraints, because you will get conflicts. You either want to create one set of constraints and change their `.constant` values (for example), or you need to set `.isActive = false` on constraints that you **don't** want active and `.isActive = true` on constraints that you **do** want active.

Comment: By the way... didn't we just go over how to do this properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876808/resize-constraints-for-uiview-swift ???

Comment: Yes you are right. Now I will rewrite some code so that you can disable properties `isActive`

Comment: @DonMag 
I tried to reset the restrictions before assigning new ones. But the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have posted several very similar questions, I ***strongly*** recommend that you spend some time learning how constraints and auto-layout work.

The imageView frames seem rather odd, as this line (for example):

```
imageOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide!.bottomAnchor,constant: 290)
```

Puts the Bottom of the imageView 290-pts ***below*** the Bottom of the view, so 290-pts (pixels) will be "off-screen."

However, here is *one* approach based on the code you posted. We define constraints for each imageView for both its "left-swipe" position/size and its "right-swipe" position/size. We store those constraints in arrays, which we can then activate / deactivate as needed:

```
class SwipeViewController: UIViewController {

    let imageOne: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    let imageTwo: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        return v
    }()

    // imageOne constraints when swiping Left
    var imageOneLeftConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    // imageOne constraints when swiping Right
    var imageOneRightConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    // imageTwo constraints when swiping Left
    var imageTwoLeftConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    // imageTwo constraints when swiping Right
    var imageTwoRightConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(imageOne)
        view.addSubview(imageTwo)

        guard let layoutGuide = view else { fatalError("this should not fail") }

        // local constraint var to reuse
        var c: NSLayoutConstraint


        // define constraints for imageOne when swiping left
        c = imageOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor)
        imageOneLeftConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        imageOneLeftConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: 170)
        imageOneLeftConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: 290)
        imageOneLeftConstraints.append(c)

        // define constraints for imageTwo when swiping left
        c = imageTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor,constant: 800)
        imageTwoLeftConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor,constant: 200)
        imageTwoLeftConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: 530)
        imageTwoLeftConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: 200)
        imageTwoLeftConstraints.append(c)


        // define constraints for imageOne when swiping right
        c = imageOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor)
        imageOneRightConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        imageOneRightConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: 299)
        imageOneRightConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageOne.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: 570)
        imageOneRightConstraints.append(c)

        // define constraints for imageTwo when swiping right
        c = imageTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor)
        imageTwoRightConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        imageTwoRightConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        imageTwoRightConstraints.append(c)
        c = imageTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        imageTwoRightConstraints.append(c)

        // start with imageViews at "swiped left" positions
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(imageOneLeftConstraints + imageTwoLeftConstraints)

        setupSwipe()
    }

    func setupSwipe() {
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
        swipeRight.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    }

    @objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        if gesture.direction == .right {

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(imageOneLeftConstraints + imageTwoLeftConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(imageOneRightConstraints + imageTwoRightConstraints)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations:{
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        } else if gesture.direction == .left {

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(imageOneRightConstraints + imageTwoRightConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(imageOneLeftConstraints + imageTwoLeftConstraints)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations:{
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try very hard to study this topic as best as possible so that no similar situations arise.